# How is having processes kept as files in `/proc` not a performance issue?

Tags: performance, proc

I understand that "everything is a file" is not entirely true, but as far as I know, every process gets a directory in `/proc` with lots of files. Read/write operations are often great bottlenecks in speed, and having to read/write from/to files all the time can significantly slow down processing.

Does having to keep a bunch of files in `/proc` slow things down? If not, how doesn't having to do a lot of IO operations not be a huge design flaw in Linux?

Comment: /proc is not a real filesystem, it's a view into the kernel's process tables.   Any overhead in maintaining this view falls somewhere between "nonexistant" and "negligible".

Comment: @cas: I would say it's almost entirely on the "nonexistent" end of the spectrum, because with very few exceptions, the kernel already has to keep track of all that information anyway, just to keep the system running correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the Unix philosophy of "everything is a file", and many things that do not exist on storage are represented using the same interface.

Comment: There is some overhead in reading out the structures by way of converting it to files and keeping some state (especially for large virtual files like the maps or sockstat), but the actual creation of processes does update the normal process structures only and is not concerned with /proc (besides some basic sane concurrent operations which would be needed for other ways to access the lists as well). In fact other methods like reading through process tables are more problematic in that regard,

Comment: @kevin I agree.  overhead is very much on the "non-existent" side of the spectrum.   But it's > zero, so non-existent isn't quite right.

Comment: @cas Not sure I understand your comment. procfs is a very real filesystem that's mounted into `/proc`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph do you honestly have difficulty understanding, or are you just being tiresomely pedantic about your own artificially narrow and contorted definition of the word "real" and how it relates to the word "filesystem"?  If the former, then the comments and answers here will tell you everything you need to know.  If the latter, then please go quibble somewhere else, in private where no one else has to be exposed to it.

Comment: @cas Please assume good faith instead of going straight for insults. I just honestly don’t understand your comment (and, what’s more, I’m baffled by the upvotes), since it’s factually incorrect (not for some “contorted” definition of “real” but rather for its most common meaning) and doesn’t seem to help OP’s understanding, on the contrary (it actively adds to OP’s confusion). I fear that it’s really doing OP a disservice.

Comment: 1. it's factually correct.  /proc is not a real filesystem.   the comments and the answers here explain why that is the case.   2.  i find it hard to believe that someone could be honestly ignorant about this topic and *still* have the chutzpah to incorrect people about it in public.  "Good faith" seems very unlikely.

Comment: @cas In that case let me reiterate my initial comment: procfs is a real filesystem (its files do not correspond to physical disk locations but that is irrelevant for the Unix/Linux concept of a file). Claims to the contrary are simply wrong, and being rude to people pointing this out doesn’t make you right. And, obviously, (contrary to your last comment) none of the comments or answers “explain” why procfs isn’t a filesystem. (And contrary to your assumption I am *intimately* familiar with Linux filesystem internals. Hacking the Linux FS was a large part of my last job.)

Answer (score 47):

Files in `/proc` and `/sys` exist purely dynamically, i.e. when nothing is reading them, they aren't there at all and the kernel spends no time generating them.

You could think of `/proc` and `/sys` files as API calls. If you don't execute them, the kernel doesn't run any code

Comment: Even *when* reading and writing them, they are *still* not there at all. When you do a directory listing, the kernel *tells* you they are there. And when you open one, the kernel *tells* you it's a file. But it isn't. In some sense, it never exists.

Comment: And in some cases, directory entries exist and can be opened but don’t appear when directories are listed. Some of the information produced when reading files *does* take a little time to generate, *e.g.* `/proc/meminfo` (with special handling to limit race conditions).

Comment: An easy but not super recommendable way to see this is to unplug your PC while its running and then attach the drive as secondary storage to another computer - none of the "files" associated with processes on the original system will be there.

Comment: @DreamConspiracy You can use a bind mount for this without having to unplug anything: `mount --bind / /somewhere/else` will show you a view of `/` mounted somewhere else, but without all the virtual filesystems like `/proc` overlaid on it.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: I think (though I don't know for sure) that accessing the info in any of those pseudo-files would take pretty much the same amount of time if done with e.g. a system call.

Comment: The point is that without a reader the files do not exist, and by not existing they consume no resources.  if there's a reader the kernel makes something up to show the reader (it looks like files and directories)

Comment: @jamesqf, for the ones that do a some relatively trivial lookup, a dedicated system call might well be faster just because it would only be _one_ system call. Reading a file from `/proc` or `/sys` requires three: `open()`, `read()` and `close()` (or two, if you're sloppy and don't close)

Comment: @JörgWMittag do not attempt to read `/proc/$SPOON`—that would be impossible. Instead try to realize the truth: there is no `/proc/$SPOON`

Comment: "Everything is a stream of bytes which may have a name"

Answer (score 29):

I think you're taking the whole "everything is a file" saying just a bit too literally. What that really means is that "everything can be accessed *as though* it were a file".

Despite what some of the other answers may say, in point of fact, *nothing* in `/proc` actually exists as a file on disk. The `/proc` filesystem doesn't take up any disk space at all, and so no I/O is spent maintaining it. This can be confirmed by unmounting the `/proc` filesystem, and looking at the disk usage numbers.*

Rather, its contents are generated dynamically when a program tries to access it. For instance, when you type `ls /proc`, what actually happens is that the kernel gets the current list of process IDs from the process table and sends them to the `ls` program as though they were regular directory names. The same thing happens with the contents of each "directory", plus all the other "directories" and "files" in `/proc`.

*On a normal system, the `/proc` filesystem is probably going to be in use, which will keep you from unmounting it. So if you actually want to perform this test, you might need to boot to single-user mode, and even then there's no guarantee of success.

Comment: It's more like, a file in Unix is an abstraction, and disk files are just one realization of that abstraction.

Comment: *This can be confirmed by unmounting the /proc filesystem, and looking at the disk usage numbers.* - what would that tell you?  It's a *separate* mounted filesystem anyway, so it's already not included in the usage info for `/` in `df -h` output.  The fact that it has no disk mountpoint at all is more revealing. `mount | grep proc` will show something like `proc on /proc type proc (...)`, as opposed to `/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type btrfs`.  It's not part of `/`, and you didn't have to make space for it when partitioning your disk.  And `while /bin/true;do :;done` doesn't cause constant I/O.

Comment: @PeterCordes The OP assumed that the files in `/proc` were real disk files, in which case, yeah, they *would* affect the disk usage numbers **somewhere**. It's also true that the `/proc` filesystem doesn't have an associated partition, but I figured the lack of change in disk used would be an easier concept to grasp.

Comment: Right, I understand what you're trying to show.  But that teaches a wrong idea about disk usage: that unmounting one FS could change reported disk usage on another.  That's never how it works.  Unless you were trying to disprove the idea that a `procfs` mount on `/proc` *would* work by creating real disk files on the underlying FS.  I guess that's a possible misconception, too, which I hadn't considered, and your experiment *is* a way for someone to rule out that misunderstanding.  Still, I think it's important to point out that no mounts ever work that way.

Comment: FWIW `du -cs /proc` returns zero bytes total size.

Comment: The idea of "everything is a file" is still subtly different from this. It's closer to "everything is an object". Unix processes work with file handles, which can be obtained from opening files on the file system, or from other API calls (such as network API calls), or from other processes. Much like in duck-typed languages, some of these file handles will respond to some APIs. You can read from a TCP socket, a pipe or a regular file, but you can't seek the socket or the pipe.

Answer (score 13):

Another way to think about `/proc` files is that while 'everything is a file', not every file is bytes stored on a disk.

For `/proc` files, reads are satisfied by the kernal dynamically generating the necessary bytes, based on the status of running processes, rather than by retrieving bytes from disk storage.

Likewise, writes on `/proc` files (where permitted) are interacting with the kernel, not with bytes on a disk.

Comment: *interacting with processes* - more usually interacting with *the kernel*, e.g. `echo 6 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`, or more normally in a boot script via `sysctl(8)`.  Are there any writable files under `/proc/<PID>/`?  (`/proc/<PID>/fd/...` are writable, but are actually symlinks to the real files, not a way to interact with the process.)

Comment: "interacting with processes" >> "not a way to interact with the process " Fair call. There are some writable files under /proc/<pid>, but I think they're all(?) to do with process specific values held by kernel. You might say that, for some of them, you're acting on a process, but that's different to saying you're interacting with a process. I'll update...

Comment: Oh you're right, there are some writeable files.  I should have checked.  Like `/proc/<PID>/coredump_filter`, or `oom_score_adj`, or even `comm` (argv[0]).  You're interacting with kernel attributes of that process, so that's fair.

Answer (score 8):

Doing much I/O *can* be a bottle-neck, especially if the underlying device (e.g. hard-disk) is slow and/or busy.

However most parts of `proc` do not actually refer to a physical device. Moreover, `proc` contains a *representation* of all the processes in the system. Some of the files refer to data, but most of that resides in RAM – which is blazing fast to access.

Indeed, accessing files can be slow. However just maintaining the directory tree without actually accessing the files and directories does not cost that much performance.

Also keep in mind that processes only rarely access their own or other's processes' representation in `proc`. A process can acceess most information directly without ever accessing `proc` manually.

Example: A process may acquire memory on heap via `malloc`. The kernel knows the process has allocated memory and represents this information via `/proc/…/maps`. The process will use the memory directly by accessing the pointer, and not by doing I/O on `/proc/…/mem`.

Comment: Which parts of `proc` refer to a physical device?

Comment: @StephenKitt I know file handles exist in `/proc/…/fd` (which in turn can refer to files on physical devices). I am not perfectly sure if there is absolutely no connection between `/proc` and physical devices.

Comment: @Hermann The contents of `/proc/.../fd` are symlinks pointing to the actual paths being accessed, not direct references to the open file descriptors, so they’re still not physical devices, and there is no actual I/O going on through `/proc` when accessing them.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's not entirely true. They do look like symlinks, but they actually work partially like hardlinks, in that they refer to a particular inode, not a path. `cat /proc/PID/fd/X` will output the contents of the exact file that PID keeps open, even if it got deleted or replaced by something different in the meantime.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn You say they're symlinks, but you can actually open them even if the symlink target is inaccessible or nonexistent. For example, I believe you can open a copy of a socket through /proc/.../fd, even though the link says it points to something like "socket:25474624342" which doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't tell an assembly programmer that RAM is blazing fast

Comment: @user253751, indeed they're not normal symlinks, but far more magic. But as far as I can tell, you can't use them to reopen a socket.

Comment: @JoshuaHyatt,  In the context of filesystems, where the comparison is a regular filesystem backed by something like a disk drive, RAM is pretty fast. Though a lot of the often-accessed parts of a regular filesystem also reside in RAM via caching. (Where ever did assembly programmers come to this? And if you're counting clock cycles, the act of making a _system call_ isn't that fast either.)

Answer (score 7):

The term “file” is heavily overloaded here. It might mean a file stored on an actual disk, but in this case it means anything accessed using the file API: open, read, write and close.

These four functions are a very generic API, and Unix always shoehorned various other things into this API. Character devices, block devices and named pipes are all accessed through the same four basic functions, but the thing being read and written is not file on a disk.

Traditionally the device files did have entries on the disk to keep the path lookup simple, but that would be inefficient for `proc` as `sys` filesystems, so they have custom lookup too and don't write anything to the disk at all. Nor does, for that matter, a `tmp` filesystem, which simply keeps the data in the cache (and possibly swaps them out to the generic swap).

So when you are not accessing them, there is no overhead at all. When you do, all it takes is allocating the dentry, inode and file structures in kernel (to tie the file descriptor to) and formatting the information from the internal kernel structures. It is a bit slower than a dedicated API would be, but it avoids having to add more entry-points to the kernel and allows utilizing existing utilities for processing the information.

Comment: Not everything can be shoehorned into open/read/write/close. That's why we have the [ioctl(2)](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/ioctl.2.en.html) call.

Comment: @roaima, I didn't say everything. And you still need a filehandle for ioctl.

Comment: Fundamentally I like your answer (+1). I was being picky about your o/r/w/c paradigm

Answer (score 3):

There is some unnecessary overhead in doing the `open` and `close` system calls. This is one reason for the [proposed introduction of the `readfile` system call](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-READFILE-Syscall-Revived).

The overhead of using a filesystem with ASCII names for /proc and /sys is completely worth it when you consider the alternatives. In the very bad old days programs had to be SUID root so that they could read kernel memory and parse the binary process structures. That was horribly buggy if userspace and kernel got out of sync. Also incredibly buggy once systems had multiple CPUs and the kernel process structures could change while being read without locking.

I believe that some of the BSDs decided to use a form of ioctl or netlink access which gives them binary access to the process data without reading the kernel directly. That is more efficient than procfs but makes it very difficult to use from shell and scripting languages.

Comment: Whether the data is encoded as text or binary is independent of whether it is sent over file API (`proc`/`sys`) or socket API (`netlink`). Text nicely abstracts away the differences between versions, platforms and configurations and is easier to use from scripts.

Comment: I must add that parsing text (it is not uncommon to condense a lot of data in a single /proc file) cannot be as efficient as a syscall that access some indexed struct in kernel.